# method to total data in a list of a class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Twice this month, I've had to create a total a bunch of records of a class. (two different classes) and this will happen again.  It seems to me that there should be an easy way to do this using reflection for any class without having to code a totaling routine for each class.

Consider:

```
private class ThisAndThat
{
    public int This { get; set; }
    public float That { get; set; }
    public double TheOther { get; set; }
    public string Whatever { get; set; }
}
```

As my code rumbles along, I create a bunch of these but I also need a totaling routine.  Something like the AddToTotal() listed below,m where the numbers are added and the string is ignored.

```
List<ThisAndThat> _Discovered = new List<ThisAndThat>(); 
ThisAndThat _Total = new List<ThisAndThat>; 
while( !Finished )
{
    ThisAndThat CurrentOne = GetAnotherOne(); 
    _Discovered.Add( CurrentOne ); 
    AddToTotal( _Total, CurrentOne ); 
}
```

Obviously the numeric three properties in this sample class are easy to code, but I just did one with 60 numeric members. I fumbled around with reflection for a while but could not come up with a routine.

Comment: Class with 60 unique numeric fields smells somewhat... Are you sure that you need to sum unrelated fields? Consider changing to list of sort...

Comment: so how do you "add" any field that doesn't have a defined "+" operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection can absolutely do this. It's not too difficult. Here's an example using the class you provided:

```
var tat = new ThisAndThat();
tat.This = 1;
tat.That = 2.0F;
tat.TheOther = 3.0;
tat.Whatever = "Whatever";

var type = typeof(ThisAndThat);
var properties = type.GetProperties();

double total = 0.0;

foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in properties)
{
    switch (pi.PropertyType.ToString())
    {
        case "System.Int32": //int
            total += (int) pi.GetValue(tat, null);
            break;
        case "System.Double":
            total += (double) pi.GetValue(tat, null);
            break;
        case "System.Single": //float
            total += (float) pi.GetValue(tat, null);
            break;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
```

Note that my sample only works with Properties.  If you have Fields that you need totaled, you'll have to use the GetFields method on the Type.

You should also be aware of handling other numeric types as well such as Int64, etc...

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ThisAndThat thisThatSum = 0;

foreach(ThisAndThat tat in _Discovered)
{
    thisThatSum.This += tat.This;
    // do the same for other fields
}
```

I'm sure a linq, way exists too, but I'd have to like do research and stuff to get that to you

Answer (score -1):

Linq to sql makes this very easy for anything IEnumerable

```
    ThisAndThat item1 = new ThisAndThat();
    ThisAndThat item2 = new ThisAndThat();

    item1.TheOther = 1.00;
    item2.TheOther = 2.00;

    _Discovered.Add(item1);
    _Discovered.Add(item2);

    var amount = from p in _Discovered
                 select p.TheOther;

    Console.WriteLine("Amount total is {0}", amount.Sum());
```